# jqBootstrapValidation.js not working in IE

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, validation

I'm using the js form validation library [jqBootstrapValidation.js](http://reactiveraven.github.com/jqBootstrapValidation/) to validate a sign up form I have. Everything works great until I try it in Internet Explorer 9.

I have "required" rules on everything among others (min/max length, valid email etc.)
In IE the validation library is only working on the email field. The only difference between the email field and the first name field is that email is of type="email" and first name is of type="text".

I have placeholder attributes on the fields and a modernizr work around for IE that loads the placeholders. Interestingly enough, when I take out the placeholder on the "first name" field, the validation library recognizes it and marks it as required.

Has anyone had trouble using this library with IE?

Comment: Everything's working fine for me in IE8. However, if you need support for earlier IE versions, you should probably consider using another validation library. For certain reasons, I have to use a branch version of jqBootstrapValidation, which will break compatibility with at least IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992465/how-did-i-validate-required-jqbootstrapvalidation-on-ie9-ios)

> the required attribute isn't supported on IE or Safari